# Prove that exists a unique subgroup $H$ of $G$ of order $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group with order $2n$, where $n$ is odd. Prove there exists a unique subgroup $H$ of $G$ that has order $n$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: The explicit definition of $H$ would be $H=\{g\in G\mid g^n=1\}$. But proving that is closed under multiplication is not obvious to me.  Basically, $H$ is the elements of odd order in $G$.

Comment: It's best to begin questions like this with what you have done so far towards an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group $G$ acts on itself by left multiplication. So $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{2n}$. Now consider the subgroup $A_{2n}$ of index $2$. Now just prove that there is an element in group **not** lying in $A_{2n}$ and we are done. It can be done by using the fact that $G$ has an element of order $2$ and $n$ is odd, hence all elements of order $2$ in $S_{2n}$ are odd.

EDIT:

Alternatively, first we prove the following Lemma:

**Lemma**: If group $G$ acts on a finite set $S$, and if there exists an element in $G$ which induces an odd permutation of $S$, then there exists a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $[G:H]=2$.

**Proof**: Let $|S|=n$. Then action gives a representation $\phi :G \to S_n$. Let $\omega :S_n \to \{\pm 1\}$ be the parity homomorphism.
The homomorphism $\omega \circ \phi :G \to \{ \pm 1\}$ is onto. Let $H$ be its kernel. Then using Isomorphism theorem, we are done. //

Now for our original question, we use the Lemma with $G$ acting on itself by left multiplication. We want an element inducing odd permutation. Let $a$ be element of order $2$. (It exists by Cauchy's theorem.)

Kerenel of this action is trivial. So $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{2n}$.

Now as $a$ has order $2$, we have if $a=\sigma_1 \cdots \sigma_m$ where $\sigma_i$'s are nontrivial disjoit cycles of $S_{2n}$, LCM of length of these cycles is $2$, i.e.: all of them are transpositions. Also $a$ fixes no elements (check yourself), $\sigma_i$'s must involve **all** $2n$ elements, i.e.: $m=n$. As $n$ is odd, $a$ induces odd permutation.

Now use the Lemma.

Comment: I don't know what $H$ is?

Comment: I also don't know *explicitly* what $H$ is,but we can see that $A_{2n}$ *corresponds* to a subgroup of original group. also,there is an alternative proof if you are not very comfortable with $A_{2n}$ that I can provide for the fact $G$ has a subgroup of index $2$.

Comment: Yes, I want you show $G$ has a subgroup of index 2, and this subgroup be uniqueness

Answer (score 2):

$|G| = 2n$ where n is odd. Then any subgroup of $N$ of order $n$ must be normal in $G$, since $|G/N|=2$ and $2$ is the smallest prime that divides the order of $G$. Now suppose that there be two subgroups $H$ and $N$ of order $n$ in $G$.  Then we can get a homomorphism $f: H \rightarrow G/N$ where $f = g\circ i$, $i$ is the inclusion map from $H$ to $G$, and $g:G \longrightarrow G/N$. Then $\text{Ker}f=H \cap N$.

$H/(H \cap N)$ is isomorphic to $\text{Image}(f)$, which is a subgroup of $G/N$.
Thus $|H/(H \cap N)|$ divides $|G/N|$ and obviously $|H \cap N|$ divides $|H| =|N|$.

In this question, $\text{gcd}(|N|,|G/N|)=1$, whence $|H/(H \cap N)|=1$.  Thus we get $H = H \cap N$.  Therefore $H \leq N$ and $|H|=|N|$ so $H=N$, whence $H$ is the unique subgroup of order $n$.